# How to put if inside if (VB)?

Tags: vb.net

How can I put an `If` inside another `If`?
Here's my code:

```
        If IsProcessRunning("javaw") = True Then

        Dim result = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        If (result = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
        ElseIf (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ok pressed")

        End If
```

This gives me error: I should put `End If` after `if IsProcessRunning()` line.
But this will cancel the first `If` statement and will show the message box if `IsProcessRunning` is `True` or `False`.

How can I fix this? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've just missed off the second `End If`, you don't have to put it where Visual Studio tells you, you just have to make sure it's there:

```
If IsProcessRunning("javaw") = True Then

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    If (result = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
    ElseIf (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ok pressed")

    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If IsProcessRunning("javaw") = True Then
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
    If (result = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
    ElseIf (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ok pressed")
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the other statements, you can nest If statements, i.e.

```
If IsProcessRunning("javaw") Then
    ...
    If (result = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        ....
    End If
End If
```

Depending on your code and situation you might however end up with a "spearhead": If you want to run you "real" code after a lot of "entry conditions" were checked to be true, you could either write:

```
Sub YourSub()
    If cond1 Then
        If cond2 Then
            If cond3 Then
                If cond4 Then
                    '"real code":
                    YourCodeHere
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As this can get quite messy, it's recommendable to invert the checks instead, i.e.:

```
Sub YourSub()
    'Entry conditions
    If Not cond1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not cond2 Then Exit Sub
    If Not cond3 Then Exit Sub
    If Not cond4 Then Exit Sub

    '"real" code
    Your CodeHere
End Sub
```